# How to condense these large if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I've been working on this code for a while now and finally completed it, but is there some way that I could possibly condense the large amount of if statements?

I've tried everything within my knowledge of coding and nothing has seemed to work.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AidanMRN{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Creating Variable "Number"
        int number;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Storing Number
        System.out.println("Pick a number, 1 - 10");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

        //If statements and Outputs
        if (number > 10)
            //Error message
            System.out.print("Error, " + number + " is higher than 10.\nPlease try again");
        if (number == 1)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: I");

        if (number == 2)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: II");

        if (number == 3)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: III");

        if (number == 4)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: IV");

        if (number == 5)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: V");

        if (number == 6)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: VI");

        if (number == 7)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: VII");

        if (number == 8)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: VIII");

        if (number == 9)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: IX");

        if (number == 10)
            System.out.println("Roman Numeral: X");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I've tried everything within my knowledge of coding and nothing has seemed to work`?

Comment: Use a `switch`-`case` statement...

Comment: @Aris_Kortex i've used everything I know about java, and looking up info hasn't helped

Comment: You could put the roman numbers into a String array and just fetch them based on the number, e.g. `String roman = romanArray[number-1];`.

Comment: switch case, or at least if else if, even if 1 == number returns true, you needlessly still evaluate all the other values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can have shorter if-statement with this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] romanNumbers= {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"};

            int number;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            //Storing Number
            System.out.println("Pick a number, 1 - 10");
            number = keyboard.nextInt();
            //If statements and Outputs
            if (number > 10 || number < 1)
                //Error message
                System.out.print("Error, " + number + " is higher than 10.\nPlease try again");
            else
                System.out.println("Roman Numeral: " + romanNumbers[number -1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is short, sweet and to the point. Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: My pleasure, It would be nice if you accept my response.

Comment: I tried to, but it said I had to wait a few more minutes.

Comment: Nice way of thinking :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Map`

```
Map<Integer, String> numbers = new HashMap<>() {{
    put(1, "I");
    put(2, "II");
    put(3, "III");
}};

System.out.println("Roman Numeral: " + numbers.get(number));
```

Comment: No it should as it relies on the antipattern of initializing a Map using double-braced initialization. Logic-wise it's correct.

Comment: [`why is double brace initialization an anti-pattern`](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

use

can be done like this

```
enter a number : 5
userNumber=5
    String [] romanNumbers = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"};
    for(int i=0;i<romanNumbers.length;i++){
if(i==userNumber &&userNumber<=10){
userNumber=userNumber-1;
Console.WriteLine("the roman Number is "+romanNumbers[userNumber]);
}
}
```

Comment: I would not  suggest to use parallel arrays / collections for simple code like this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using a `switch` statement as an alternative to those `if`s:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creating Variable "Number"
    int number;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Storing Number
    System.out.println("Pick a number, 1 - 10");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();
    // If statements and Outputs
    switch (number) {
    // error message for number < 1 AND number > 10
    default:
        System.out.print("Error, " + number 
                + " is less than 1 or greater than 10.\nPlease try again");
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: I");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: II");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: III");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: IV");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: V");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: VI");
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: VII");
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: VIII");
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: IX");
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: X");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in the Main Method. Personally I would use a loop for the Error message, but this use of an array works.

```
    //Creating Variable "Number"
    int number;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Storing Number
    System.out.println("Pick a number, 1 - 10");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();

    String [] romanNumeral = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"};

    if(number > 10)
    {   
        System.out.print("Error, " + number + " is higher than 10.\nPlease try again");
    }
    else
    {   
        System.out.println("Roman Numeral: " + romanNumeral[number-1]);
    }
```

Comment: Oh someone else wrote code the same way as me above.

Answer (score 0):

An example answer could be this one:

```
public class RomanNumerals {

    private static final Map<Integer, String> NUMERAL_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(1, "I");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(2, "II");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(3, "III");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(4, "IV");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(5, "V");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(6, "VI");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(7, "VII");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(8, "VIII");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(9, "IX");
        NUMERAL_MAP.put(10, "X");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input a number [1-10]: ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        Optional<String> found = Optional.ofNullable(NUMERAL_MAP.get(input));
        if (found.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Found numeral: " + found.get());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No numeral found for input: " + input);
        }
    }

}
```

You basically initialize a map key a key value of an integer and a string value of the numeral. Then by iterating the map's keySet you attempt to find the corresponding value.

Comment: True the iteration was not needed. As for the concrete null, this was done in case the OP did not have any experience with Optionals (where the null-check is much more easier to understand).